# Create a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I want to write a loop for the following function in R:

```
Idents(immune) = "seurat_clusters"
immune.0 = subset(immune, idents = ("0"))
Idents(immune.0) = "stim"
immune.0_markers = FindAllMarkers(object=immune.0, only.pos=TRUE, logfc.threshold=0.25)
write.csv(immune.0_markers,"immune.0markers.csv")
save(file='immune.0.Rdata',immune.0)

Idents(immune) = "seurat_clusters"
immune.1 = subset(immune, idents = ("1"))
Idents(immune.1) = "stim"
immune.1_markers = FindAllMarkers(object=immune.1, only.pos=TRUE, logfc.threshold=0.25)
write.csv(immune.1_markers,"immune.1markers.csv")
save(file='immune.1.Rdata',immune.1)

Idents(immune) = "seurat_clusters"
immune.2 = subset(immune, idents = ("2"))
Idents(immune.2) = "stim"
immune.2_markers = FindAllMarkers(object=immune.2, only.pos=TRUE, logfc.threshold=0.25)
write.csv(immune.2_markers,"immune.2markers.csv")
save(file='immune.2.Rdata',immune.2)

Idents(immune) = "seurat_clusters"
immune.3 = subset(immune, idents = ("3"))
Idents(immune.3) = "stim"
immune.3_markers = FindAllMarkers(object=immune.3, only.pos=TRUE, logfc.threshold=0.25)
write.csv(immune.3_markers,"immune.3markers.csv")
save(file='immune.3.Rdata',immune.3)
```

I attempted the following, the clusters are called "seurat_clusters" from 0 to 20.

```
for (i in 0:20){
    Idents(immune) = "seurat_clusters"
    immune.i = subset(immune, idents = ("i"))
    Idents(immune.i) = "stim"
    immune.i_markers = FindAllMarkers(object=immune.i, only.pos=TRUE, logfc.threshold=0.25)
    write.csv(immune.i_markers,"immune.imarkers.csv")
    save(file='immune.i.Rdata',immune.i)
}
```

But it keeps giving error that it cannot recognize the function.

Comment: Have you try with `immune.i = subset(immune, idents = as.character(i))` ? does it give you the same error ?

Comment: @joran, I agree, the `immune.i` is also a big mistake.

Comment: immune.i = subset(immune, idents = as.character(i)) works. It doesn't give me the error. But it doesn't give me individual files. They just overwrite the same files with name "immune.i.Rdata" and "immune.imarkers.csv"

Comment: I got it to work. I'll post the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to save individual files:

Solution:

```
for (i in 0:20){
  Idents(immune) = "seurat_clusters"
  immune.i = subset(immune, idents = as.character(i))
  Idents(immune.i) = "stim"
  immune.i_markers = FindAllMarkers(object=immune.i, only.pos=TRUE, logfc.threshold=0.25)
  write.csv(immune.i_markers, paste0(i,".csv"))
}
```

Comment: I'm glad that it works for you. However, just by curiosity, how it works ? You are not going anymore for seurat cluster to 0:20 ?

Comment: Oops. Sorry I got it to work from 0:20, I just did a small subset to test.